# How to install library that uses g77

Tags: gcc

I am trying to install "TAUCS" (http://www.tau.ac.il/~stoledo/taucs/) library. However, I am getting following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible external/lib/linux/libmetis.a when searching for -lmetis
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmetis
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lg2c
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: [build/linux/taucs_config_tests.h] Error 1 (ignored)
obj/linux/taucs_c99_complex_test build/linux/taucs_config_tests.h
make: obj/linux/taucs_c99_complex_test: Command not found
make: [build/linux/taucs_config_tests.h] Error 127 (ignored)
cc -c -O3 -Wall -Werror -std=c99    -DMACHTYPE_ -I src/ -I build/linux/ -I external/src/   \
      progs/taucs_cilk_test.c \
      -oobj/linux/taucs_cilk_test.o
progs/taucs_cilk_test.c:8:19: fatal error: cilk.h: No such file or directory
 #include <cilk.h> 
                   ^
```

more errors follow.

I think that this error arises as I already use gcc which uses gfortran instead of g77.

1) I could get the old file by doing this:

```
wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gcc-3.4/libg2c0_3.4.6-6ubuntu5_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i --force-all libg2c0_3.4.6-6ubuntu5_i386.deb
```

This created following files in /usr/lib/

```
libg2c.so.0
libg2c.so.0.0.0
```

2) After that, I found online link which suggests to create soft link, like this:

```
cd /usr/lib
ln -s libg2c.so.0 libg2c.so
```

I guess that I have include this along with

```
CILKC=$(CC)
```

So, I commented out this line and added soft link.

But, I get the following error:

```
build/linux/makefile:11: *** commands commence before first target.  Stop.
```

Some guidance would be appreciated?

Update based on @steeldriver answer:
After I did as suggested by aforementioned user, everything complied fine. But, I am getting some warnings **which I am VERY concerned about**.

```
usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible external/lib/linux/liblapack.a when searching for -llapack
....
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible external/lib/linux/libf77blas.a when searching for -lf77blas
...
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible external/lib/linux/libcblas.a when searching for -lcblas
....
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible external/lib/linux/libatlas.a when searching for -latlas
....
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible external/lib/linux/libmetis.a when searching for -lmetis
```

I think that issue could be that these library may be 64 bits vs 32 bits.
Is it possible to have both versions of libraries? I could put less frequent in /usr/local/lib. How could I ensure that a particular versions of libraries are linked in makefile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it build *correctly*, but I was able to build TAUCS 2.2 on 32-bit Ubuntu 12.04 using gfortran as follows

1. Download the *Version 2.2 of the code, with external libraries, tgz format*

   ```
   wget http://www.tau.ac.il/~stoledo/taucs/2.2/taucs_full.tgz
   ```
2. Unpack it in your chosen location

   ```
   mkdir taucs_full

   tar xvf taucs_full.tgz -C taucs_full

   cd taucs_full
   ```
3. <s>If you didn't already do so, install `libf2c2-dev` (for `libf2c`)</s>

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libf2c2-dev
   ```
4. Remove the `-Werror` flag from the global compiler options file (there **are** going to be warnings, so it will never build if we treat them as errors)

   ```
   sed -i 's/-Werror//g' config/linux.mk
   ```
5. Now run the `configure` script

   ```
   ./configure
   ```
6. Finally we need to  do some command and library wrangling for the actual `make`

   ```
   make "CC=gcc" "FC=gfortran -ff2c" "LIBF77=-Wl,-Bdynamic -lgfortran"
   ```

You should get a binary executable in `./bin/linux` - I don't have any means to test it functionally but it at least runs:

```
$ bin/linux/taucs_run 
taucs_run: there is no matrix!
```

Comment: After I did as suggested by you , everything complied fine. But, I am getting some warnings which I am VERY concerned about. Please have a look at my update in the original question.

Comment: Well provided that it *is* finding the *compatible* libraries (which it must be, I think - else `ld` would complain and wouldn't build the executables) you should be OK. OTOH the reason I used `taucs_full` is I couldn't identify the correct `metis` library: if you have `libmetis` on your system, I suggest trying again using the version **without** the external libs but otherwise following the same steps.

Answer (score 1):

@steeldriver's answer didn't work as-is for me, so I adapted it as follows. I only changed steps 3 and 6, and added the Testing part.

I'm using a completely fresh Ubuntu 14.04 32 bit. (Note that using 64 bit makes things more complicated.)

### Compiling

1. Download the *Version 2.2 of the code, with external libraries, tgz format*

   ```
   wget http://www.tau.ac.il/~stoledo/taucs/2.2/taucs_full.tgz
   ```
2. Unpack it in your chosen location

   ```
   mkdir taucs_full

   tar xvf taucs_full.tgz -C taucs_full

   cd taucs_full
   ```
3. Install the packages `gfortran` and `libf2c2-dev`. (I don't know why @steeldriver removed installing the lib from his list.)

   ```
   sudo apt-get install gfortran libf2c2-dev
   ```
4. Remove the `-Werror` flag from the global compiler options file (there **are** going to be warnings, so it will never build if we treat them as errors)

   ```
   sed -i 's/-Werror//g' config/linux.mk
   ```
5. Now run the `configure` script

   `./configure`
6. Finally we need to do some command and library wrangling for the actual `make`. (This command is different from the one in @steeldriver's solution.)

   ```
   make "CC=gcc" "FC=gfortran -ff2c" "LIBF77=-Wl,-Bdynamic -lgfortran -lf2c -u MAIN__"
   ```

You should get a binary executable in ./bin/linux and the lib in ./lib/linux.

## Testing

To test the lib I used the file `test_taucs.cpp` from [this site](http://matrixprogramming.com/2008/12/taucs):

1. Put `test_taucs.cpp` in the `taucs_full` folder
2. Install g++

   ```
   sudo apt-get install g++
   ```
3. Compile the cpp file

   ```
   g++ test_taucs.cpp -I ./src -I ./build/linux/ -L lib/linux/ -ltaucs -L external/lib/linux -llapack -lf77blas -lcblas -latlas -lmetis -Wl,-Bdynamic -lgfortran -lm -lf2c  -u MAIN__
   ```
4. Run a.out

   ```
   ./a.out
   ```

The output should contain the solution (0 2 0 4) as described in the linked blog post.