# gcc: Skipping incompatible libraries and returning error

Tags: gcc

This question is related to my [previous question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/576127/how-to-install-library-that-uses-g77). I am trying to install the ["TAUCS"](http://www.tau.ac.il/~stoledo/taucs/) library

TAUCS is a C library of sparse linear solvers. It has dependency on BLAS, ATLAS, LAPACK, METIS etc.

I followed the solution of @steeldriver and it worked on one of my ubuntu computer, but not on other.

On other computer, I get the following error:

```
$ sudo make "CC=gcc" "FC=gfortran" "LIBF77=-Wl,-Bstatic -lf2c -Wl,-Bdynamic -lgfortran"
mkdir obj
mkdir obj/linux/
echo exists > obj/linux/exists.log
gcc -c -O3 -Wall  -std=c99    -DMACHTYPE_ -I src/ -I build/linux/ -I external/src/   \
      progs/taucs_blas_underscore_test.c \
      -oobj/linux/taucs_blas_underscore_test.o
gcc   \
      -oobj/linux/taucs_blas_underscore_test \
      obj/linux/taucs_blas_underscore_test.o -L external/lib/linux -llapack -L external/lib/linux -lf77blas -lcblas -latlas -L external/lib/linux -lmetis  -Wl,-Bstatic -lf2c -Wl,-Bdynamic -lgfortran -lm 
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible external/lib/linux/liblapack.a when searching for -llapack
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible external/lib/linux/liblapack.a when searching for -llapack
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible external/lib/linux/liblapack.a when searching for -llapack
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible external/lib/linux/libf77blas.a when searching for -lf77blas
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible external/lib/linux/libf77blas.a when searching for -lf77blas
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible external/lib/linux/libf77blas.a when searching for -lf77blas
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lf77blas
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible external/lib/linux/libcblas.a when searching for -lcblas
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible external/lib/linux/libcblas.a when searching for -lcblas
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible external/lib/linux/libcblas.a when searching for -lcblas
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcblas
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible external/lib/linux/libatlas.a when searching for -latlas
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible external/lib/linux/libatlas.a when searching for -latlas
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible external/lib/linux/libatlas.a when searching for -latlas
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -latlas
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible external/lib/linux/libmetis.a when searching for -lmetis
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible external/lib/linux/libmetis.a when searching for -lmetis
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible external/lib/linux/libmetis.a when searching for -lmetis
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmetis
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: [build/linux/taucs_config_tests.h] Error 1 (ignored)
obj/linux/taucs_blas_underscore_test build/linux/taucs_config_tests.h
make: obj/linux/taucs_blas_underscore_test: Command not found
make: [build/linux/taucs_config_tests.h] Error 127 (ignored)
gcc -c -O3 -Wall  -std=c99    -DMACHTYPE_ -I src/ -I build/linux/ -I external/src/   \
      progs/taucs_blas_nounderscore_test.c \
      -oobj/linux/taucs_blas_nounderscore_test.o
gcc   \
      -oobj/linux/taucs_blas_nounderscore_test \
      obj/linux/taucs_blas_nounderscore_test.o -L external/lib/linux -llapack -L external/lib/linux -lf77blas -lcblas -latlas -L external/lib/linux -lmetis  -Wl,-Bstatic -lf2c -Wl,-Bdynamic -lgfortran -lm 
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible external/lib/linux/liblapack.a when searching for -llapack
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible external/lib/linux/liblapack.a when searching for -llapack
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible external/lib/linux/liblapack.a when searching for -llapack
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible external/lib/linux/libf77blas.a when searching for -lf77blas
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible external/lib/linux/libf77blas.a when searching for -lf77blas
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible external/lib/linux/libf77blas.a when searching for -lf77blas
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lf77blas
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible external/lib/linux/libcblas.a when searching for -lcblas
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible external/lib/linux/libcblas.a when searching for -lcblas
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible external/lib/linux/libcblas.a when searching for -lcblas
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcblas
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible external/lib/linux/libatlas.a when searching for -latlas
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible external/lib/linux/libatlas.a when searching for -latlas
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible external/lib/linux/libatlas.a when searching for -latlas
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -latlas
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible external/lib/linux/libmetis.a when searching for -lmetis
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible external/lib/linux/libmetis.a when searching for -lmetis
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible external/lib/linux/libmetis.a when searching for -lmetis
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmetis
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: [build/linux/taucs_config_tests.h] Error 1 (ignored)
obj/linux/taucs_blas_nounderscore_test build/linux/taucs_config_tests.h
make: obj/linux/taucs_blas_nounderscore_test: Command not found
make: [build/linux/taucs_config_tests.h] Error 127 (ignored)
gcc -c -O3 -Wall  -std=c99    -DMACHTYPE_ -I src/ -I build/linux/ -I external/src/   \
      progs/taucs_c99_complex_test.c \
      -oobj/linux/taucs_c99_complex_test.o
gcc   \
      -oobj/linux/taucs_c99_complex_test \
      obj/linux/taucs_c99_complex_test.o -L external/lib/linux -llapack -L external/lib/linux -lf77blas -lcblas -latlas -L external/lib/linux -lmetis  -Wl,-Bstatic -lf2c -Wl,-Bdynamic -lgfortran -lm 
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible external/lib/linux/liblapack.a when searching for -llapack
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible external/lib/linux/liblapack.a when searching for -llapack
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible external/lib/linux/liblapack.a when searching for -llapack
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible external/lib/linux/libf77blas.a when searching for -lf77blas
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible external/lib/linux/libf77blas.a when searching for -lf77blas
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible external/lib/linux/libf77blas.a when searching for -lf77blas
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lf77blas
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible external/lib/linux/libcblas.a when searching for -lcblas
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible external/lib/linux/libcblas.a when searching for -lcblas
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible external/lib/linux/libcblas.a when searching for -lcblas
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcblas
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible external/lib/linux/libatlas.a when searching for -latlas
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible external/lib/linux/libatlas.a when searching for -latlas
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible external/lib/linux/libatlas.a when searching for -latlas
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -latlas
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible external/lib/linux/libmetis.a when searching for -lmetis
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible external/lib/linux/libmetis.a when searching for -lmetis
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible external/lib/linux/libmetis.a when searching for -lmetis
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmetis
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: [build/linux/taucs_config_tests.h] Error 1 (ignored)
obj/linux/taucs_c99_complex_test build/linux/taucs_config_tests.h
make: obj/linux/taucs_c99_complex_test: Command not found
make: [build/linux/taucs_config_tests.h] Error 127 (ignored)
gcc -c -O3 -Wall  -std=c99    -DMACHTYPE_ -I src/ -I build/linux/ -I external/src/   \
      progs/taucs_cilk_test.c \
      -oobj/linux/taucs_cilk_test.o
progs/taucs_cilk_test.c:8:19: fatal error: cilk.h: No such file or directory
 #include <cilk.h> 
                   ^
compilation terminated.
make: [build/linux/taucs_config_tests.h] Error 1 (ignored)
gcc   \
      -oobj/linux/taucs_cilk_test \
      obj/linux/taucs_cilk_test.o -L external/lib/linux -llapack -L external/lib/linux -lf77blas -lcblas -latlas -L external/lib/linux -lmetis  -Wl,-Bstatic -lf2c -Wl,-Bdynamic -lgfortran -lm 
gcc: error: obj/linux/taucs_cilk_test.o: No such file or directory
make: [build/linux/taucs_config_tests.h] Error 1 (ignored)
obj/linux/taucs_cilk_test build/linux/taucs_config_tests.h
make: obj/linux/taucs_cilk_test: Command not found
make: [build/linux/taucs_config_tests.h] Error 127 (ignored)
mkdir bin
mkdir bin/linux/
echo exists > bin/linux/exists.log
mkdir lib
mkdir lib/linux/
echo exists > lib/linux/exists.log
gcc -c -O3 -Wall  -std=c99    -DMACHTYPE_ -I src/ -I build/linux/ -I external/src/   \
    -DTAUCS_CORE_GENERAL \
    src/taucs_sn_llt.c \
    -oobj/linux/taucs_sn_llt.o
In file included from src/taucs_sn_llt.c:13:0:
src/taucs.h:6:32: fatal error: taucs_config_tests.h: No such file or directory
 #include <taucs_config_tests.h>
                                ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [obj/linux/taucs_sn_llt.o] Error 1
```

When I look at following location, I find those files:

```
$cd /home/dkumar/taucs_full/external/lib/linux
$ls
blas_aux.o  CVS  libatlas.a  libcblas.a  libf77blas.a  liblapack.a  libmetis.a
```

How could I fix this "incompatiable libraries" issue?

Comment: Is the second machine running a 64-bit OS? the TAUCS tarball comes with a bunch of pre-built 32-bit archive libraries: there will be some extra hoops to jump through if you want to build it on a 64-bit platform (either replacing all those libs with 64-bit ones, or adding 32-bit build support to your platform and building the whole thing as a 32-bit application).

Comment: @steeldriver somehow I missed your comment, my apologies. I added 32 bit support as described: [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/454253/how-to-run-32-bit-app-in-ubuntu-64-bit) . Could you please let me know what changes should I make in makefile?

Comment: Sorry - I tried a bunch of stuff but was unable to get it to build on 64-bit. I don't think the instructions linked in your last comment are sufficient (or, possibly, helpful at all): you'd need at least `gcc-multilib` and `gfortran-multilib`, and then add `-m32` to the flags for both `gcc` and `gfortran`. That eliminates the 'skipping incompatible libraries' errors but other errors still prevent a successful build.

Comment: your answer in my previous question did allow me to build it on 64 bit linux. But, that was my other computer. I can run it on other linux by just copying "libtaucs.a". Please let me know if you want this file.

Answer (score -1):

you have to install binutils package you are missing some binaries

> sudo apt-get install binutils -y

Comment: I am still getting the same error. When I tried installing binutils package, I get :the following message `$ sudo apt-get install binutils -y
[sudo] password for dkumar: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
binutils is already the newest version.
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libg2c0:i386 : Depends: gcc-3.4-base:i386 (= 3.4.6-6ubuntu5) but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).`

Comment: ok you have already installed that package some thing is wrong with installation of that package or missing path on installed packages -- try this command "apt-get -f install"

Comment: I still get the same error. Possibly, there is something wrong about `libg2c0:i386 : Depends: gcc-3.4-base:i386 (= 3.4.6-6ubuntu5) but it is not installable`

Comment: can you reomve packages and reinstall them again ?

Comment: It seems that I will get into larger trouble as following would be removed: `The following packages would be removed: network-manager-pptp-gnome, libg2c0:i386, gcc-4.8-multilib, dkms, hardening-includes, virtualbox-guest-dkms, gcc-multilib, gfortran-4.8, pptp-linux, gcc, playonlinux, lintian, gfortran, gcc-4.8, network-manager-pptp`