# How to downgrade to GCC v.7 (Ubuntu 22.04 LTS)?

Tags: gcc, g++, compiler

I was using g++ v11 and got a compiler error (" *internal compiler error: in expand... ") which as far as I read was introduced in version 8 of g++.

So I tried to downgrade to g++ v7 just to end with my assignment (university stuff) but since I'm on Ubuntu 22.04, I couldn't in any possible way because it won't let me download any obsolete package (deleting g++ doesn't sound like a solution).

The message after trying to install g++7 is

```
Package g++-7 is not available, but is referred to by another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source.
```

Do you know how can I downgrade to g++-7?

Thank you all for your help and if you know other solutions it would be appreciated.

Comment: See the solution here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/576127/how-to-install-library-that-uses-g77